# Setting toolbar as transparent when not at the top?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I currently have a fragment with a toolbar that "disappears" when scrolling down and "reappears" on scroll up but I want to change it so that the background of the toolbar is transparent if it's showing and not all the way at the top (or even just ALWAYS transparent). This is what I currently have:

activity_fragment.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

I've tried `android:background="@null"` on both the Toolbar and the AppBarLayout but that didn't work.

I suspect the issue is with the how/where I inflate the recylerview that gets displayed beneath the the `fragment_container`:

FragmentAlbumGallery.java:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_gallery, container, false);
        mAlbumRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAlbumRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
return v;
}
```

fragment_recycler_gallery.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityGallery"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Screenshot of what my fragment looks like now:
[image: https://imgur.com/dRsCOar]

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the style **CustomActionBar**:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

That's all, folks

Comment: Sadly that's not it :|